# Placing the kinect in another place at turtlebot

Tags: kinect, turtlebot, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm building a robot based on the software of turtlebot, but i need to place the kinect sensor in another place. But the original source code specifies the kinect in another place, so I believe I would get wrong data. So, which files have I need to modify to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Lucas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11827/placing-the-kinect-in-another-place-at-turtlebot/) by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 497 on 2011-11-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will need to update the URDF to reflect the new Kinect placement. Also, if the Kinect is not level as in the current turtlebot, navigation and calibration probably won't work.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucascoelho](https://answers.ros.org/users/1016/lucascoelho/) on 2011-11-12**:
I think that must be a way to make the things work properly because i've seen a lot of modifications of turtlebot on the internet that uses the kinect in another places at the robot. I will try to update the URDF like you said and i will post my results. Thanks for the help.